VBA Row and Named Column Selection
I very New to VBA and am trying to find out how to take 2 values form the same row and different columns subtract them and give an output for that row. Then repeat that process for set range/ number of rows. I'm trying to make a timer that updates if any values are changed/ manually overwritten.
Im New to this so there's probably a simple fix, I can get it to give the selected row I want but cant get it to give the column if I do .cells for example. Also all the named variables correspond correctly to a excel sheet.


Sub TimeCalcs()
Dim x As Workbook
Set x = Workbooks("DOWNTIME PROGRAM - ZJ.xlsm")

'===================================================================================================================
Set SSButton = x.Sheets("Downtime").Range("timer.button.label") 'This is the cell the button lable is in
Set StartTime = x.Sheets("Downtime").Range("time.stamp.start") 'This is the row for the start time cell (B15)
Set EndTime = x.Sheets("Downtime").Range("time.stamp.end") 'This is the row for the end time cell (H15)
Set TimeDiffrence = x.Sheets("Downtime").Range("time.diffrence") 'This is the row for the duration cell (C15)
Set RowOffSet = x.Sheets("Downtime").Range("count.of.timestamps") 'This is the offset for the rows. It is a value that is stored too keep trak of the number of rows that have been input.
Set OnOffButton = x.Sheets("Downtime").Range("timer.button.label") 'This is the cell the button lable is in

'===================================================================================================================

Dim SDE As Range
Dim cel As Range
Set StartTimeRange = x.Sheets("Downtime").Range("StartTimeRange") 'Turns defind column cells for start time into ranges for the code (B16:B50)
Set EndTimeRange = x.Sheets("Downtime").Range("EndTimeRange") 'Turns defind column cells for end time into ranges for the code (H16:H50)
Set DurationRange = x.Sheets("Downtime").Range("DurationRange")
Set SDE = x.Sheets("Downtime").Range("Durations")

'===================================================================================================================


For Each Row In SDE.Rows

    If IsEmpty(StartTimeRange) = False And IsEmpty(EndTimeRange) = False Then
    DurationRange.Value = EndTimeRange.Value - StartTimeRange.Value
    
    Else
        
    End If
    
Next Row
    
End Sub




Please, don't post a screenshot

"I'm trying to make a timer that updates if any values are changed/ manually overwritten." -> What you are describing seems simple enough to be solved with formulas (and always avoid unnecessary VBA when you can). But if you really need VBA, the correct way to do that is with event handlers on sheets (Calculate, Change), definitely not timers.

When I say timer I mean I have VBA code that takes the start time and end time with corresponding button presses. This then puts them into a table. That then finds the duration. The problem is the values need to be manually overwritten and still calculate the others based off the changed value. Anyway I am just have an issue with  having a value corresponding cell. For example I have rows 15-50 then X,Y,Z columns. I want X to equal Z-Y for the current row then move to the next row and do the same thing.  But I keep getting a Type mismatch error when running it.


Assuming the quantity of cells in DurationRange is same as StartTimeRange.

StartTimeRange is a range which has more than one cell, so using IsEmpty(StartTimeRange(i)) to check the i-th cell in the named range.


    Dim i As Long
    Set StartTimeRange = x.Sheets("Downtime").Range("StartTimeRange") 'Turns defind column cells for start time into ranges for the code (B16:B50)
    Set EndTimeRange = x.Sheets("Downtime").Range("EndTimeRange") 'Turns defind column cells for end time into ranges for the code (H16:H50)
    Set DurationRange = x.Sheets("Downtime").Range("DurationRange")
    
    '===================================================================================================================
    
    For i = 1 To DurationRange.Cells.Count
        If IsEmpty(StartTimeRange(i)) = False And IsEmpty(EndTimeRange(i)) = False Then
            DurationRange(i).Value = EndTimeRange(i).Value - StartTimeRange(i).Value
        End If
    Next


The If clause could be simplified as

    If Not (IsEmpty(StartTimeRange(i)) Or IsEmpty(EndTimeRange(i))) Then

